# Problem with reading a binary file in cpp?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, file-handling

I have a binary file called "input.bin" where every character is of 4 bits. The file contains this kind of data:

```
0f00 0004 0018 0000 a040 420f 0016 030b
0000 8000 0000 0000 0000 0004 0018 0000
```

where 0f is the first byte.

I want to read this data and to do that, I am using the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
      char buffer[100];
      std::ifstream myFile ("input.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
      myFile.read (buffer, 100);

      if (!myFile.read (buffer, 100)) {
        std::cout << "Could not open the required file\n";
      }
      else
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
          std::cout << "buffer[" << i << "] = " << static_cast<unsigned>(buffer[i]) << std::endl;
        }
        myFile.close();
      }
    return 0;
}
```

Currently I am printing just four bytes of data, and when I run it, I get this output:

```
buffer[0] = 0
buffer[1] = 24
buffer[2] = 0
buffer[3] = 0
```

Why is it not printing the value of 0f and just printing the value of 18 in index 1 whereas it is actually at index 6?

Comment: Write your output into a text file first, then open this file and check it with some smart text editor like NotePad ++, Sublime Text ect . Windows console is not the best thing to test characters.

Comment: You probably want to print in hex instead. 3 of the 4 characters you are printing are unprintable. Look at the low values in ASCII table: [https://www.asciitable.com/](https://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: cast to int before printing

Comment: `<< buffer[i]` --> `<< static_cast<int>(buffer[i])` -- Then you actually see the decimal  values, not box characters and blanks.

Comment: @VictorGubin My input file will always be in this format, so I need to read it as it is. As for the printing, I am running the program in linux CLI. I have also run it in an IDE and its still giving me the same output.

Comment: BTW, your decoding is actually wrong. Byte have 8 bits, not 4. So when you've read it from file, you've taken two characters at time.

Comment: @VictorGubin I know that. That is why I mentioned this: "where 0f is the first byte"

Comment: You're skipping over the first 100 bytes by reading twice.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks! That was the solution!

Comment: @molbdnilo Could you add that as the solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
myFile.read (buffer, 100);

if (!myFile.read (buffer, 100)) {
```

where you read twice, and thus ignore the first 100 bytes (if there are more than 100 of them).

Remove the first `read`, or change the condition to `if (!myFile)`

Answer (score 1):

You print the contents of the data as *characters*. And none of the first four bytes are really printable characters.

You need to print them as (unsigned) integers:

```
// Unsigned bytes to avoid possible sign extensions in conversions
unsigned char buffer[100];

...

// Convert the bytes to unsigned int for printing their numerical values
std::cout << "buffer[" << i << "] = " << static_cast<unsigned>(buffer[i]) << '\n';
```

Comment: Changing the type of buffer from char to unsigned char gives me this error: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::char_type* {aka char*}’ [-fpermissive]
       myFile.read (buffer, 100);

Comment: Any help with the above problem?

Comment: @MobiZaman Cast in the `read` call: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer)`.